# SetOnClickListener cause unable to start acitivity component

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclicklistener

I currently making a application however, I'm faced unable to start the activity `componentsInfo`. I found a lots of solutions on the net, but none of them  is works for me. I try to clean my project file and restart `Eclipse`, errors still occur. I try to debug with `DDBS`, and find a '`setOnClickListener`' had something wrong. I try to edit it. But error still occur.

Note: Implements `view.OnClickListener` didn't works for me also.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private Button mBreakfast;
    private Button mLunch;
    private Button mDinner;
    private Button mSnack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    mBreakfast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_breakfast);
    mLunch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_lunch);
    mDinner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dinner);
    mSnack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_snack);


    mBreakfast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RestInfoFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting exactly? can you please post your error log here.

Comment: are you sure that your R.id.XYZ are all there in the same layout as R.layout.activity_main ? 
Post your logcat for a more specific answer

Answer (score 0):

And well it is probably a mistake to import!

if so:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

change to:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

RestInfoFragment is a fragment, and you want to start it on click of the button?

Fragments aren't invoked like Activities using Intents.To start a fragment, use this code:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, new RestInfoFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your naming , I guess the RestInfoFragment is a Fragment, and you are using a button click in another activity to navigate to the RestInfoFragment, like an Activity.

You can't use Fragment as an activity. Either change your RestInforFragment to extend a FragmentActivity or inflate the fragment in a view.

If you extends FragmentActivity , you don't need any changes to the current MainActivity.

If you are using Fragment

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, new RestInfoFragment).commit();
```

If your RestInfoFragment is using the whole screen , I recommend the use of FragmentActivity.